# React Native/Redux and react-native-router-flux: Why doesn't Actions.key work inside an action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Using React Native and react-native-router-flux with redux, I have an action creator and inside I tried using Actions.key, in this case Actions.home, but it does not work. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my action creator:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

export const navigateHome = (text) => {
  Actions.home //This does not work for some reason

  return {
    type: actionTypes.NAVIGATE_HOME_SUCCESS,
  }
}
```

And my Home `<Scene/>` is set up like so:

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene component={Login} initial={true} key='login' title='Login'/>
            <Scene component={Home} key='home' title='Home' type={ActionConst.REPLACE}/>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

But when I tested inside a component with `<Text onPress={Actions.home}>Continue</Text>`, it navigated to `<Home/>` fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Actions.home()` in `navigateHome`, you cannot just do `Actions.home` without the `()`.

Comment: it did the job! but why can't just Actions.home work like it does in components such as onPress={Actions.home}?

Comment: Because onPress requires a non-called function. Under the hood that function gets called for you.

Comment: Need your expertise again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657899/how-to-implement-react-native-drawer-in-react-native-router-flux-with-redux